# Starting service doesn't work with "Unfortunately, App has stopped". No stack trace exception

Tags: android, kotlin, service

minSdkVersion 19
compileSdkVersion 29
targetSdkVersion 29

When my Application is trying to start a service, it works fine with `SdkVersion >= 24`.

But the service crashes with an "Unfortunately, App has stopped." if I try it with `SdkVersion < 24`. `OnCreate()` of the service is never called. The activity still runs, only the service crashes with the popup.

Nothing in the stack trace shows an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Check Below Code :

> Android can (and will) stop your Service whenever it wants to. Because
>   you have returned START_STICKY from onStartCommand(), Android should
>   restart your Service after it has been killed. In this case you will
>   get a null Intent in onStartCommand() after the restart. There is no
>   way to prevent Android from killing your Service if it wants to.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: The service onStartCommand() returns START_STICKY.
On KitKat to Marshmallow, the onCreate() and onStartCommand() aren't even called.
Nougat and above, the Service works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Please add service in AndroidManifest.xml and use below code.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```